# how to daisy chain with system having 2 ethernet ports and a bridge on each system, and such n systems with external router present/absent?

Tags: python, linux, networking, network-programming

Lets say each node has 2 ethernets, eth0 and eth1, my connection would be eth1 of nth system connects eth0 of n+1 system so on. and in each system eth0 and eth1 need to be bridged to allow udp broadcast traffic. and there are two scenarios on powerup.

my strategy is first connect node to network and then power up, so that my startup script residing in node runs to find if router exists or not and based on that it make the system get configured as normal node or as router. and consecutive device connected to it and powered up after first one, to see first device as router or get ip from external router.

1. The first system's eth0 may be connected to external router, in which case every system's eth0 suppose to get ip from the external router.
2. if there is no external router, then the first system should act as router and provide ip address to rest of the systems.

on every bootup i want default setting run frist, even if previous run it had worked as router. so that it behaves as per the requirement

here is my script writtern in python.. but it behaving totally wrong in everysense. bridge not showing both interfaces bridged. on consecutive boot up device acted as router fail to configure itself as node. system connected to eth1 of first node dont get ip address.. etc

blame it on chatgpt ;)

````
import os

# Set the PAGER environment variable to "cat" to prevent paging
os.environ["PAGER"] = "cat"

# Check if the bridge already exists
BRIDGE_NAME = "br0"
INTERFACE1 = "eth0"
INTERFACE2 = "eth1"

bridge_exists = False
try:
    subprocess.check_call(["nmcli", "con", "show", BRIDGE_NAME], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    bridge_exists = True
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    bridge_exists = False

# Check if the myrouter connection already exists
myrouter_exists = False
try:
    subprocess.check_call(["nmcli", "con", "show", "myrouter"], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    myrouter_exists = True
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    myrouter_exists = False

# Remove the myrouter connection if it exists
if myrouter_exists:
    os.system("nmcli con delete myrouter")

# Create the bridge if it doesn't exist
if not bridge_exists:
    os.system(f"nmcli con add type bridge ifname {BRIDGE_NAME} con-name {BRIDGE_NAME}")
    os.system(f"nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname {INTERFACE1} master {BRIDGE_NAME}")
    os.system(f"nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname {INTERFACE2} master {BRIDGE_NAME}")

# Define the IP address of your router
ROUTER_IP = "192.168.0.1"

# Ping the router to check its availability
def is_router_available():
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(["ping", "-c", "1", ROUTER_IP])
        return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False

if is_router_available():
    print("Router exists. Using default configuration.")
else:
    print("Router not found. Configuring enp5s0 as a router.")

    # Set up enp5s0 as a router using NetworkManager
    os.system(f"nmcli con add type ethernet ifname {INTERFACE1} con-name myrouter ipv4.method shared")
    os.system(f"nmcli con modify myrouter ipv4.addresses '192.168.0.1/24'")
    os.system("nmcli con up myrouter")```
````